# Bootstrap 3 Fluid Container with centered content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, dreamweaver, fluid-layout

I'm sure this might be a simple one but I haven't figured it out yet.

How do you create a full screen fluid container and have the content, including the navigation, be centered on the page, as in a non-fluid container?

I'm just trying to get the top nav/header background to stretch across the page while keeping the content at a fixed width.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can surround the `.container` with your navigation content with another `<div>` on which you add the background styling. See the following example:

```css
.background {
  background-color: #f99;
}

.content {
  background-color: #9f9;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="background">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 content">Content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what if there's a background image and I want it to be continued in the background but the rest of the content remain the same?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't completely understand your question. Is for example the background image taller than your content and does the bottom part get cut off. Or do you for example want a full height background image?

Answer (score 1):

A rough method is to use the Bootstrap grid concept.
Bootstrap divides your row into 12 colums.
The trick consists into the insertion of a 4-black-space block before and one after your 4-space block.
Example:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
      
  <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
      
  <div class="col-sm-4">
   <h2>Title</h2>
   <p>Your content here</p>
  </div>
      
  <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```